# BPMN API/Database Diagram, Good practice

Tags: uml, analytics, bpmn

For my Master Thesis, I was planning to do some BPMN diagram explaining the differents "flows" between the client, the API and the Database. I've look for similar diagrams in BPMN but I did not find any.

Could anyone tell me if this kind of diagram is good practices? I let an example under :

[image]

Comment: This is an activity diagram, with activity partition. To use activity is a good practice yes

Comment: Thank you for your response Bruno, have a nice day !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BPMN diagrams are used for presenting of business processes and does not support well the system level details. This might be a reason why you couldn't find examples close to what you expect.

UML should be your choice as it offers you a range of diagram types specifically for what you want to achieve.

Typical choice here would be be Activity Diagram (which would look pretty much similar to your diagram, just some elements would be slightly different - end activity would use a different icon with a black ball inside and decision node will be empty; moreover you'll need a fork/join elements where there are two parallel flows).

Other option, as good as the previous one, would be a Sequence Diagram. it will be entirely different though. Yet it emphasises the responsibilities of Client, API and Database and how the messages are passed between them.

If you're less interested in the sequence of messages you may also consider Communication Diagram.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look at UML and check if I can find good examples with Activity diagram.

Comment: Don't limit your research to activity diagram only. Since you are mentioning the usage of JSON or the "request API" I would expect you might find sequence diagram even more suitable.

Comment: There is pro and cons, I find activity diagram more "clear" even if messages are more clear with sequence diagrams

Comment: BPMN is not a diagram but a language (like UML). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation In fact, UML offers a profile to emulate BPMN.

Comment: @ThomasKilian you're right of course. I have rephrased my answer slightly. I don't want to use the term "language" directly as it might confuse OP but I think it is OK now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, that's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What looks the most to what you're doing seems to be an Activity Diagram (as said by `Ister` just above) but **specifically using swimlanes**: [Activity Diagram with swimlanes](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/#activity-diagram-swimlane)

[image]

On the same page you have the [specification of all notations](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-activity-diagram/#activity-diagram-notation-summary)